# Refunds from Google Merchant Account while testing with real product IDs

Tags: google-play

Context: I have tested my app with static response, but now I want to test with real product IDs, So I followed from developer site "Testing In-app Purchases Using Your Own Product IDs"
Now when I made purchases I have to refund from my merchant account, The refund links on the order is not enabled, (Note: I have not added bank account to receive the money in merchant account). I see Cancel Entire Order button, but refund amount in there is 0, So can any one tell me how to refund?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Give Google some time](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138001?hl=en):

"To ensure a safe purchasing environment and compliance with our Terms of Service, our specialists review Checkout merchant accounts on a regular basis. During this time, you will be temporarily unable to process refunds through your account. [...] Also rest assured that you will be able to resume processing refunds through your account 24 hours after your refund attempt is first declined. We appreciate your patience during this time.